How to use date-fns instead of dayjs when creating custom calender header for MUI Date Picker
I am trying to add a custom calender header for the MUI Date Picker component but am running into troubles when changing the default dayjs type to date-fns.
Here is my Date Picker component and custom header component.
<StyledDatePicker
            open={open}
            value={date}
            onChange={(newValue) => onChange(newValue as Date)}
            slots={{
              openPickerIcon: CalendarIcon,
              shortcuts: CustomRangeShortcuts as any,
              calendarHeader: CustomCalendarHeader,
            }}
            slotProps={{
              actionBar: {
                actions: ['today'],
              },
              shortcuts: {
                items: MUI_DATE_PICKER_SHORTCUTS,
              },
              openPickerButton: {
                onClick: iconButtonOnClick,
              },
              textField: { variant: 'filled', onFocus: inputFocused, onBlur: close },
            }}
          />

const CustomCalendarHeader = (props: PickersCalendarHeaderProps<Date>) => {
  const { currentMonth, onMonthChange } = props;

  const selectNextMonth = () => onMonthChange(currentMonth.add(1, 'month'), 'left');
  const selectNextYear = () => onMonthChange(currentMonth.add(1, 'year'), 'left');
  const selectPreviousMonth = () => onMonthChange(currentMonth.subtract(1, 'month'), 'right');
  const selectPreviousYear = () => onMonthChange(currentMonth.subtract(1, 'year'), 'right');

  return (
    <CustomCalendarHeaderRoot>
      <Stack spacing={1} direction="row">
        <IconButton onClick={selectPreviousYear} title="Previous year">
          <KeyboardDoubleArrowLeftIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton onClick={selectPreviousMonth} title="Previous month">
          <ChevronLeft />
        </IconButton>
      </Stack>
      <Typography variant="body2">{currentMonth.format('MMMM YYYY')}</Typography>
      <Stack spacing={1} direction="row">
        <IconButton onClick={selectNextMonth} title="Next month">
          <ChevronRight />
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton onClick={selectNextYear} title="Next year">
          <KeyboardDoubleArrowRightIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </Stack>
    </CustomCalendarHeaderRoot>
  );
}

The custom header prop type in the example uses Dayjs (PickersCalendarHeaderProps<Dayjs>) but I want to use date-fns, how can I implement this using date-fns instead of dayjs?

To use date-fns you need to update the LocalizationProvider. Search for the file where you implemented the localization provider. Replace the dayjs adapter with date-fns adapter. Check this MUI doc: https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/adapters-locale/#with-date-fns

I have already wrapped the the date picker in the date fns localisation provider. This is more how I implement this function using date fns, as the example uses dayjs.

The date-fns provides similar functions as day.js. Check the code below: 
import { addMonths, addYears, subMonths, subYears } from 'date-fns';

const selectNextMonth = () => onMonthChange(addMonths(currentMonth, 1), 'left');
const selectNextYear = () => onMonthChange(addYears(currentMonth, 1), 'left');
const selectPreviousMonth = () => onMonthChange(subMonths(currentMonth, 1), 'right');
const selectPreviousYear = () => onMonthChange(subYears(currentMonth, 1), 'right');

These changes will work the same as what you were doing with day.js.
